# What would happen if there was no friction on earth?

Tags: friction

I'm not talking about zero-g or a vacuum.  If oxygen, gravity, air pressure, etc still existed but if there was suddenly no friction, anywhere.

Comment: Does this removal include viscosity..? (i.e. Airplane friction)

Comment: All friction between molecules

Comment: Friction is just a result of matter interacting with each other, so I'm not sure what it means to have "nothing change except friction". To get rid of friction you'd have to get ride of things like Newton's laws and electric charge.

Comment: Questions asking hypothetical situations such as this is considered off-topic here.

Comment: There is no friction between molecules. Friction is a mesoscopic phenomenon that happens under all circumstances as long as there is some interaction between multiple parts. In a world without any interaction there is, of course, no physics whatsoever, which makes any kind of question for the physics of such a world superfluous. If you want to know what frictionless functional designs are, look no further than ordinary gear train engineering. Engineers are trying their absolutely best to reduce friction to the minimum while maintaining strong interaction and quite successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Friction is essentially the name people assign to the electromagnetic interactions on the everyday scales. Your question then comes down to asking what the universe will be if no electromagnetic interaction were present, which is the same as asking what the universe will be if we replaced the interactions we currently have with something else.

The answer is as simple as the question: there is no way to tell, as there is no way to tell why our universe works the way it does. Physics does not investigate why laws are there, it only describes such laws by means of mathematical languages.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to imagine Earth of that sort. We would all be dead. We have evolved with Friction, and there's no way, absolutely no way, our bodies could do the bodily functions (e.g. blood pressure would be so high, it would burst out arteries!).
The question is ill-posed.